# How to have repeated items in an Ordered To-Many relationship?

Tags: ios, core-data, nsarray, relationship

In Core Data of Xcode 4.3.2, an Ordered To-Many relationship is modelled with `NSOrderedSet`. It works well until I found the need to have repeated items in the relationship; it should really be modelled in a `NSArray`.

For example, in a music app, I have the following songs: `SongA, SongB, SongC` ,

I may want a party play list where people insert songs in any order and could be repeated. The list may look something like:

```
[SongC, SongC, SongA, SongC]
```

The way Core Data currently works, the list would become:

```
[SongC, SongA]
```

I.e., all repeated items are dropped, as it is modelled with sets.

So, coming back to my question: what is a good way to model repeated items in order in a relationship in Core Data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relationships are sets (and ordered relationships are ordered sets, but still sets); sets by definition contain unique objects. So you can't put duplicate objects into a relationship either way.

Whether you use the ordered-relation feature or not, you'll want to go back to the abstract ER model to find another way to turn your conceptual relationships into a Core Data model... it might help to think about how you'd do it in a plain SQL (or SQL-like) database and then come back to what Core Data does beyond SQL.

It sounds like you're making something akin to iTunes playlists, no? A model that might work for that would go something like:

```
 Playlist      <--->> PlaylistEntry
 PlaylistEntry <<---> Song
```

The `PlaylistEntry` entity represents one instance of a `Song`'s inclusion in one `Playlist`. You can have multiple `PlaylistEntry`s that reference the same `Song` in a single `Playlist`, and you can add other attributes to the `PlaylistEntry` to keep track of other things (like song order, if you're not using an ordered relationship). As a bonus, you can use that to add other features if you like -- say, to make a playlist that plays three different snippets out of one long track.

Answer (score 1):

As rickster said, relationships as managed by Core Data uniquely associate entities between them. Even if Lion's Core Data (is supposed to) supports ordered relationships (supposed to, because in practice it won't work, the feature is buggy, barely usable), they still are relationships that follow the relational database model.

And so you have to manage the association by yourself, and you most certainly have to manage the ordered part of the association by yourself too.

```
Score <->> ScoreSong
ScoreSong <<-> Song
```

With ScoreSong having the following properties:

```
ScoreSong:
- score: -> Score
- song: -> Song
- order: integer, indexed
```

Then you have to use a Fetch Request with a sort descriptor for the key order, which will return an ordered NSArray of ScoreSong. You can ask the fetch request to prefetch the songs, then you can create the songs array, still properly ordered, with a single call to valueForKey: @"song".

Of course you have to create different ScoreSong for a single Song when you need to include than song more than once in your Score. That's the whole point of the added indirection.

Comment: There is a radar for the ordered relationships issue: http://openradar.appspot.com/search?query=10935136 . Mine's 11500860.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and link, fabrice. I also encountered the exception/bug you raised; I thought that was a bit odd... But I'm able to use ordered set fairly happily. :)

Comment: If you uses the default controllers and UI, yes, it works nicely. I think. Custom code is another story, I've been bitten quite hard and now I lost any confidence in the feature. I do not want to take the risk knowing the KVO stuff for ordered relationships is broken in some places.